# php empty result for language table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to add multiple language options with the database. I created a table as follows.

[image]

And my PHP function is:

```
    public function Languages(){
     $query=mysqli_query($this->db,"
SELECT  * FROM languages") or die(mysqli_error($this->db)); 
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                 $data[]=$row;
              }
             if(!empty($data)) {
                // Store the result into array
                return $data;
              } 
            }
```

So also I used the following code for showing result but I am getting the empty result:

```
<?php 
  $language = $ReSult->Languages();
   $userLanguage = 'english';
   echo  $language['your_family'][$userLangauge];
?>
```

I know if I use `$language['1'][$userLanguage];` then I get a result but I don't want to use id's here. Is there any way to do that to show results without using ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the results in an associative array:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[$row['lang_key']] = $row;
}
```

This way, you can access the data directly by its key:

```
echo $language['your_family'][$userLangauge];
```

Comment: I did not know how to do it. Thank you, dear.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this

```
function getIndex($language  , $key)
{
  foreach ($language as $row) 
  {
    if (strcmp($row["lang_key"] , $key)==0) {
      return $row["id"]
    }  
  }
  return null;
}

...

echo $language[getIndex($language , "your_family")][$userLanguage];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[$row['tagKey']] = $row;
}
```